# Is it possible to convert ArcGIS 9.3 lyr to ArcGIS 10 lyr

Tags: arcgis-10.0, layers, format

I have a customer who sent me a lyr file in ArcGIS 9.3 and I am using ArcGIS 10,  is there a way to import it in.  It seems to hang up whenever I attempt to open it!

Comment: You can open 9.3 lyr in 10 but you cannot do 10 lyr in 9.3.

Comment: Can you add the data (probably a shapefile or geoDB) directly to ArcMap without the LYR file? If yes, the LYR file may be corrupt. If no, the data file(s) may be corrupt or missing.

Answer (score 2):

@prasad is right you can open 9.3 lyr in 10.

if you want to save them to 10 lyr `right click your layer` and select `Save As Layer File` then select `Layer files (*.lyr)` from `Save as type` and now you can save it as 10 lyr .

---

The reverse operation is told [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7108/arcgis-9-doesnt-recognize-arcgis-10-lyr-files) ArcGIS 9 doesn't recognize ArcGIS 10 .lyr files and solution:

> If you right click on your layer in ArcGIS 10 and click 'Save As Layer
>   File', in the 'Save as type' dropdown box you will have an option to
>   save the .lyr file as a 9.3 layer file, which should let you use the
>   symbology in 9.3.

Beside this for batch convertion you can use Save To Layer File (Data Management)  with arcpy, [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000070000000).

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data"
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("studyquadsLyr", "C:/output/studyquadsLyr.lyr", "ABSOLUTE")
```

i hope it helps you